# Game with 2 players : choosing two points

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n$ points on the plane such that no three are collinear. A and B play the following game. The two players will take turn choosing two points that haven't been connected with the line segment and draw the line to connect those two points. The winner is one who draws the line segment and make all points be the endpoints of at least one line segments. Find all $n\geq 5$ that if A plays first, B will win no matter how A chooses the points.

Is my answer correct ?

At one point after the two players have played the game for a period of time, there are 3 points that haven't been connected with the line segment.

Let $X$ be the set of first $n-3$ points that are chosen and $Y$ be the set of the last $3$ points.

We claim that the answer is $n \equiv 0, 3 \;(\bmod{4})$ for $n \geq 5$.

As $n \equiv 0, 3 \;(\bmod{4})$ so $\frac{(n-3)(n-4)}{2} = \binom{n-3}{2}$ is even.

Since $n$ is even and A plays first , A will be the one who choose one point in set $X$ and one point in set $Y$ to draw a line, after that B will choose the two points, both in set $Y$, this makes all points be the endpoints of at least one line segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks good but I would say it like this:

If $\binom{n-3}{2}$ is  even then player $2$ can win. This is because whenever he has to move while there are more than $3$ unused points he can always add a segment that does not use any of those $3$ points (because $\binom{n-3}{2}$ is odd so not all segments will have been used). So eventually he will obtain a position in which there are $2$ or $1$ unused points and he can win.

If $\binom{n-3}{2}$ is odd then player $1$ can win. This is because whenever he has to move while there are more than $3$ unused points he can always add a segment that does not use any of those $3$ points (because $\binom{n-3}{2}$ is odd so not all segments will have been used). So eventually he will obtain a position in which there are $2$ or $1$ unused points and he can win.

Finally we have that $\binom{n-3}{2}$ is even when if $n\equiv 3,0\bmod 4$ and we have $\binom{n-3}{2}$ is odd if $n\equiv1,2\bmod 4$.